# WebStorm/PhpStorm ES6 syntax support not working

Tags: ecmascript-6, phpstorm

I cannot get the ES6 styles and auto complete to work in PhpStorm version 2017.1.3 in Linux.

I've enabled it in the options and waited for the program to re-index but still its not working.

Are there any other steps I can take to get this working?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: The error on your first screenshot comes from JSHint -- looks like it was not configured to accept ES6 syntax (JSHint and other linters are configured separately).

Comment: ah... great shout! I will look at our rules. Although this file passes our `npm t`

Comment: Ah, its JSHInt, not ESLint. I see now